# How do I report a bug when Launchpad fails?

Tags: apt, bug-reporting, launchpad

I'm installing xubuntu 18.04.1 fresh, less than 15 minutes after the install finished I had a problem with vim-nox (a.k.a /usr/bin/vim.nox).  I tried "ubuntu-bug vim-nox" and things got weird very fast.  Almost immediately I saw a message like this: 
(apport-gtk:13898) dbind-WARNING: ...
reporting a problem with "accessability bus".  It was repeated.  It did not ask for anything so I ignored it.

A firefox window opened, and it asked if I wanted to proceed.  I did.  Then it said Ooops! Something went wrong in Launchpad............

I'm reporting this using an older system, so I'm not copying all the details.

What I'm asking for is some channel to report this, or find a fix.  I think the Launchpad problem is much more important than the original vim-nox thing.  So that's what I'd like to solve.

I'm not going to try much with 18.04 until bug reporting works at the very least.

Comment: try ubuntu-bug vim-nox again

Comment: I just tried again on a system running 16.04 that has been stable all along.  It fails in exactly the same way reporting the same bug.

Comment: So I'm starting suspect a real bug in Launchpad, and perhaps they'll live up to their promise (sent when the bug happens) to look into it and get it working quickly.

Comment: It's always necessary to provide the OOPS ID that Launchpad gives you.  While it's opaque to you, Launchpad staff can look it up and find out what happened; without that there's nothing we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Retry using step by step way:

1. (apport) Save the collected bug info locally

   ```
   apport-cli -f -p PACKAGENAME --save FILENAME.apport
   ```
2. (lp) Open Launchpad in a browser, Register/Login and Make new bug report against related package.
3. (apport & lp) Upload the saved data to that new report

   ```
   ubuntu-bug -c FILENAME.apport -u BUGNUMBER
   ```
4. (lp) Wait few minutes, then recheck if data were processed correctly into that report.

**Reference:** [Ubuntu Help - Bug Reporting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

If it fails in any step, submit a report directly to LP/Launchpad against tool between parentheses.